# Spring Boot connectando no banco Microsoft Sql Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou tentando connectar em banco do SQl Server 2008, porém esta dando este erro:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falha na conexão com o host ERSERVER, instância nomeada \sqlern_desenv. Erro: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verifique os nomes do servidor e da instância e verifique se nenhum firewall está bloqueando o tráfego UDP para a porta 1434. Para o SQL Server 2005 ou posterior, verifique se o serviço SQL Server Browser está sendo executado no host

application.properties:

```
datasource:
  bar:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ER_NETWORK
    username: postgres
    password: 123

  foo:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://ERSERVER:\\SQLERN_DESENV;database=BD_TESTE;integratedSecurity=true
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    username: sa
    password: 123
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Alguem tem um exemplo de conexão?